# Grayscale to RGB - Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, image-manipulation

I can't get a grayscale image in RGB, here's my code:

```
img=cv2.imread("clahe_2.jpg")
backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
showImg(backtorgb,"claheCLR")
```

This error returns:

```
backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9765: error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function cvtColor
```

Filepath is correct.
Any suggest?

Comment: 1) If you want `imread()` to read in greyscale, you should set the flag to `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` on `imread()`. 2) If you want to revert to a colour image, you should be aware that OpenCV uses BGR ordering in general.

Comment: Kindly print `img.shape` so we can see the number of channels in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I think tat problem is that your image is not real grayscale. It is RGB, but visible as grayscale. So need to bring one channel from image and then run the code:

`backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(img[..., 0], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`

Comment: If the problem is that the image is RGB visible as greyscale, there is no need to convert it to RGB surely?

Comment: Yes. The main response is that image formats like *.jpg, *.png cannot store grayscale image and always contains multichannel data.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: PNG and JPEG certainly can store grayvalue (single-channel) images.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `imread` opens the image as a 3-channel BGR image so you don't need to convert it, maybe just to RGB if that's what you're looking for.

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the application of the CLAHE filter and its grayscale output, actually the output kept the 3 channels but at the sight it looked like a grayscale, documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html).

I simply found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008458/how-to-apply-clahe-on-rgb-color-images) a method that kept the RGB form to solve the problem, thanks to everyone for the answers.

Comment: Y, not mentioned.. my bad :)