# Histogram Equalization before extracting color on a real time video

Tags: opencv, blob, histogram, rgb

Is it a good practice to use the histogram equalization on the colored image before extracting its color during a real-time video stream? I have seen some people using but I have not seen any tutorial doing that. How does it behave with luminosity changes? Are there certain cases that it might help?

Comment: What do you mean by "before extracting its color"?

Comment: yes, to pre-process the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you doing histogram equalization you need to first color convert it to a color space with a luminance channel, like Lab, HSV or YCrCb and then only equalize the luminance. If you try equalizing the RGB channels you will get weird color shifts.

Comment: But even if I base my detection in the shifted colors?

Comment: I read your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341114/simple-illumination-correction-in-images-opencv-c/24341809#24341809 . Can this be applied on real time applications?

Comment: The full code is in that post; best to time it yourself on your images and hardware. Note that you could go MUCH faster than my implementation by using the GPU versions of cvtColor and CLAHE (possibly you need 3.0 for the latter)