# Color levels in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I want to do something similar to the [levels function in Photoshop](http://cdn.cambridgeincolour.com/images/tutorials/levels_psex1.png), but can't find the right openCV functions.

Basically I want to stretch the greys in an image to go from almost white to practically black instead of from almost white to slightly greyer, while leaving white as white and black as black (I am using greyscale images).

Comment: That's right. OpenCV is much better! =)

Comment: Wait, if photoshop isn't opencv, does that explain why my code doesn't compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a function mapping input levels to output levels as shown below in the figure.

[image]

For example, the orange curve is a straight line from (a, c) to (b, d), blue curve is a straight line from (a, d) to (b, c) and green curve is a non-linear function from (a,c) to (b, d).

We can define the blue curve as (x - a)/(y - d) = (a - b)/(d - c).
Limiting values of a, b, c and d depend on the range supported by the channel that you are applying this transformation to. For gray scale this is [0, 255].

For example, if you want a transformation like (a, d) = (10, 200), (b, c) = (250, 50) for a gray scale image,

y = -150*(x-10)/240 + 200 for x [10, 250]

y = x for [0, 10) and (250, 255] if you want remaining values unchanged.

You can use a **lookup table** in OpenCV (**LUT** function) to calculate the output levels and apply this transformation to your image or the specific channel. You can apply any piecewise transformation this way.

Comment: Lookup tables it is, then. I was hoping there would be an answer that didn't involve them.

Answer (score 8):

The following python code fully implements Photoshop Adjustments -> Levels dialog.

Change the values for each channel to the desired ones.

`img` is input rgb image of `np.uint8` type.

```
inBlack  = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.float32)
inWhite  = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.float32)
inGamma  = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=np.float32)
outBlack = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.float32)
outWhite = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.float32)

img = np.clip( (img - inBlack) / (inWhite - inBlack), 0, 255 )                            
img = ( img ** (1/inGamma) ) *  (outWhite - outBlack) + outBlack
img = np.clip( img, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Playing with inBlack and outBlack values is sufficient to get the desired effect. Thanks @iperov!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what are the "Photoshop levels". But from description, I think you should try the following:

1. Convert your image to YUV using [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor). Y will represent the intensity plane. (You can also use Lab, Luv, or any similar colorspace with separate intensity component).
2. Split the planes using [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20split(const%20Mat&%20src,%20Mat*%20mvbegin)), so that the intensity plane will be a separate image.
3. Call [equalizeHist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=equalizehist#equalizehist) on the intensity plane
4. Merge the planes back together using [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20merge(const%20Mat*%20mv,%20size_t%20count,%20OutputArray%20dst))

Details on histogram equalization can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html)

Also note, that there's an implementation of somewhat improved histogram equalization method - CLAHE (but I can't find a better link than [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html), also @berak suggested a good [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341114/simple-illumination-correction-in-images-opencv-c/24341809#24341809) on the topic)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341114/simple-illumination-correction-in-images-opencv-c/24341809#24341809) might be the missing link to CLAHE

Comment: I'm using greyscale images, if that changes anything. I guess that would mean I don't have to convert, split then merge right? Just the equalizeHist bit.

Comment: Unfortunately equalizeHist seems to be eating up some of the colors in my image. Where there was several tones of very light gray now there is only black and very few tones of dark gray, so I can't use it.

Comment: To repeat myself, you can also try to use CLAHE, which is an "adaptive" alternative to global histogram equalization.