# Tesseract not recognising text in image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract in python 3.11 to convert some images to text on Windows 11. I have tried preprocessing the images including morphing, enlarging, greyscaling and thresholding but nothing seems to work.

I have been chopping and changing my code but the below is where I have got to (path is the local path for each image) -

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as tess

tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread(path)
greyscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold = cv2.threshold(greyscale, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

data = tess.image_to_string(threshold, config='--psm 6')
print(data)
```

I'm open to using other libraries.

Comment: To improve recognition, set another threshold `threshold = cv2.threshold(greyscale, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]` and invert the image so that black numbers are on a white background. And set the whitelist `custom_config = r'--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="9876543210"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust color level of your image to remove background.

[adjust Color level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJx79.png)

```
inBlack = np.array([170, 170, 170], dtype=np.float32)
inWhite = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.float32)
inGamma = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=np.float32)
outBlack = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.float32)
outWhite = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.float32)

img = cv2.imread(file_path)

int8 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img)

color_level = np.clip((int8 - inBlack) / (inWhite - inBlack), 0, 255)
color_level = (color_level ** (1 / inGamma)) * (outWhite - outBlack) + outBlack
color_level = np.clip(color_level, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

[Color levels in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60339950/22844558)

and then, change image to grayscale and apply threshold.

[greyscale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lopP8.png)

[threshold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKM2Q.png)

finally, invert your image to tesseract recognize your image well.

[inverted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6s0w.png)

```
inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(threshold)
```

Comment: additionally, you must increase your image size as @Yunus Temurlenk says.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @le2dy Thanks! Do you know how you adjusted the color levels? I'm struggling to match the image you produced. I attempted to use the link you provided but failed. Alternatively, if you have the code you used, I can investigate from that

Comment: @Vik I changed the value of "inBlack". Image that I produced is the result of adjusting color level.

Comment: @le2dy perfect thank you! I've got it to work and have accepted your answer.

Answer (score -1):

According to the tesseract [documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/tess3/FAQ-Old.md#is-there-a-minimum--maximum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text)

> Is there a Minimum / Maximum Text Size? (It won't read screen text!)
>
> There is a minimum text size for reasonable accuracy. You have to
> consider resolution as well as point size. Accuracy drops off below
> 10pt x 300dpi, rapidly below 8pt x 300dpi. A quick check is to count
> the pixels of the x-height of your characters. (X-height is the height
> of the lower case x.) At 10pt x 300dpi x-heights are typically about
> 20 pixels, although this can vary dramatically from font to font.
> Below an x-height of 10 pixels, you have very little chance of
> accurate results, and below about 8 pixels, most of the text will be
> "noise removed".
>
> Using LSTM there seems also to be a maximum x-height somewhere around
> 30 px. Above that, Tesseract doesn't produce accurate results. The
> legacy engine seems to be less prone to this (see
> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tesseract-ocr/Wdh_JJwnw94/24JHDYQbBQAJ).

So first thing to do is that increasing the size of your input image since they re under the limited size. Then you may apply **wiener** or some kind of filters to improve the quality again. `EasyOCR` can be another option too instead of `tesseract`

Comment: Number recognition has only worsened due to your proposal, since a font with cut corners was used.

Comment: @СергейКох without resizing to a higher sizes it will not be possible to read acc. to the doc. So resizing to a higher size is  a must. After that some improvements I have suggested